# mvc datetime to name of the month

Tags: model-view-controller, model

I have a property in my model as:
public DateTime created_dt {get;set;}

I want to view the month name for this in my view
I am using created_dt.ToString("mmmm") but it is showing 00 as the value.

Why is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```cs
 created_dt.ToString("MMMM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use capital M in `ToString()`